# Flask SQLAlchemy with Postgresql, autocommit does not work without a query after inserting a record

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have configured the DB connection in my flask app this way:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = conn_url
session_options = {
    'autocommit': True
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options=session_options)
```

In my view code,

```py
req_body = request.json
db.session.add(XYZ(**req_body))
```

where XYZ is my db.Model, does not insert the record into the table.
Neither the flush() or commit() from sqlalchemy gets executed.

But, adding a query after the add flushes the session changes into the DB and inserts the record.

```py
req_body = request.json
db.session.add(XYZ(**req_body))
XYZ.query.all()
```

I don't think this is the desired behaviour with autocommit enabled.
Can someone please comment on this or let me know if I'm missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you import the SQLAlchemy object?

Comment: Autocommit should not be used, especially so with `Session`. I think it is working as expected, since `Session.add()` simply adds the target to the session, but it does not emit any SQL at that point. Adding a query after results in autoflush kicking in, which then emits the INSERT to which autocommit applies.

Comment: @BrunoLubascher I add all the DB configuration options into a separate file at the top level and import the `db` variable into all my models

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yeah, makes sense. Since I have autocommit enabled, I cannot use commit() without transactions. I figured out that session.flush() and then session.refresh() does the job for me.